# Create multiple dataframe columns by performing calculation on combinations of existing column

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to create a number of dataframe columns that correspond to the results of the same calculation being performed on different combinations of a single existing column.

For the sake of example, let's say the specific problem is tracking distances between points on a line. My initial dataframe would look something like this, where x is the point's position:

```
points <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
```

For each point, I would like to calculate the distance from each other point and store them as separate columns say `d1`, `d2`, `d3`, `d4`, and `d5`.

I can add a column manually using:

```
points$d1 <- lapply(points$x, function(x) abs(x - points$x[1]))
```

I've run into problems like this a few times and my gut tells me that there is a better way to do this. Regardless of whether there is a neat solution like `mutate` from `dplyr` or I have to write a larger function, I would like to avoid `for` loops if I can.

Its also totally possible that I'm using the wrong terminology in describing this problem.

Comment: Something like `cbind(points, as.data.frame(as.matrix(dist(points$x, diag=T, upper=T, method="manhattan"))))`? (It just needs renaming.)

Comment: @r2evans, this is very helpful and I never would have thought of it. Thank you so much.